# Using Arduino to read BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, tizen-wearable-sdk, hm-10

I have an Arduino MEGA2560, I hooked it up to a BLE module HM-19 through serial. I can send AT commands and receive responses from the HM-19 successfully.

I have a BLE Smart wristwatch. This BLE smart wristwatch stores my Daily steps, Heart rate & Blood Oxygen.

I can send AT commands to my HM-19 BLE module to successfully connect to my BLE Smart wristwatch. However, after connecting/pairing the HM-19 and the smart wristwatch there doesn't seem to be much I can do.

**Question**: What AT commands do I have to send to read the wristwatches BLE services and characteristics?
I want to read the daily step counts, heart rate, blood oxygen, battery percentage, etc.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: This is not a systems design roundtable.

Comment: Systems design round table? I'm asking a question about which commands to use for reading BLE data. 
Please how is that a Systems design question?

Comment: Every BLE device offers different services and there is not much we can do without knowing which ones your smartwatches is using. There are some standard ones that can be used for Heart rate etc., but it is not a requirement to use them. A manufacturer can use some custom protocol as well. Please use a BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to analyze the offered services and characteristics. Also try to read and write to the characteristics

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the documentation for the HM-19 module it looks like it might be difficult to do what you are looking for as the product looks like it focuses on supporting UART over BLE.

[image]

The only customisation is what UUIDs are used for the two UART characteristics.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @ukBaz. I no longer use the Arduino MEGA2560. I found another solution.